# Showing option at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android

I am new to this android.In my application when user clicks Menu button ,i want to show 1 option at the bottom of the screen(background should remain as the current screen).Simply i have to say means if user clicks menu button as like pop up window 1 option should come at the
bottom of the screen.And user clicks on that some action should happen..I can t able put some screenshots for this.

```
----------------------


                           ------------>Consider this is screen


---------------------
                           ------------>here the option should come.     
----------------------
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done, but the solution is too long for me to post here, so instead follow the link to a tutorial for creating a menu

- http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/

Just as a brief overview of the tutorial - You start by overriding the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method. In this you inflate your menu. Then you override the `onItemSelected` method, in which you pu a switch to determine which option phase been selected, though in your case it will only be one item. Finally you have to create an XML file which contains all the options for your menu.

Answer (score 4):

[Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) is generally used to  give extra functionality to an application.

To achieve your goal you have to implement menu, which will open when you click menu button of device, like below.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionmenu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

R.menu#

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/Color" android:title="Color">
           <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/RedColor" android:title="Red"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/GreenColor" android:title="Green"/>
        </menu>
   </item>

</menu>
```

and if you want to do any action on click of option menu, you have to override `onOptionsItemSelected` to do action on click of menu option, like below.

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(item.getItemId()==R.id.RedColor)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MenuOptionDemoActivity.this,"Red Color Selected" ,1000).show();
        }
        else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.GreenColor)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MenuOptionDemoActivity.this, "Green Color Selected", 1000).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

A clear and simple [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/option-menu-context-menu-in-android/) to implement menu in your app.